# fancyfoot on the last page

Tags: fancyhdr, lastpage

On the last page of my document, I need to add `Next Review Date: blah blah`.  If I add the text at the bottom of the document, there is a possibility that the text might appear on a new page on its own. Ideally, I need something like `\fancyfoot[L]{Next Review Date: blah blah}`, which only appears on the last page. I wonder how this can be done.

Comment: Do you want all the page style plus this footer? Or only this footer on the last page?

Comment: I have already used \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} on all pages.  I have not used \fancyfoot[L] in my document. I would like \fancyfoot[L] to appear on the last page only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets define a new page style to be loaded only on the last page.

```
\makeatletter
\def\myrev{Next Review Date:}
\def\ps@lastpage{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@evenhead\@empty%
  \def\@oddfoot{{\slshape\myrev}\hfil\thepage}%
  \def\@evenfoot{{\slshape\myrev}\hfil\thepage}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
here is the last page
\thispagestyle{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

Only the page with the command `\thispagestyle{lastpage}` will have the same footer, independently if it is even or odd.

Comment: This overwrites \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

Comment: @Reza, I've just edited. Please, check.

Comment: @Reza, since you want on the last page only your remark and the page number, you should define the headers empty for this page style using `\let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@evenhead\@empty`, otherwise some other page style could duplicate the page number. I'll edit.